# full long bitwise in C#/SQLServer application

Tags: c#, sql, enums

In our application we are using an `enum` as type to define what Officer are involved in a particular Office activity, for example:
*in Security Activity the roles involved can be Security Officer, Security Control Officer, Security Manager etc...*

This detail are completely configurable, so we can add another official role to the activity by UI in our system simply add specific bit to bitwrise value, this value are stored in a field of Activity table, and all types is stored in a sql table; This field is used by some stored procudure, and some business intelligence are based upon this field

```
[Flags]
public enum eFatEnumBW : long
{
  None = 0,
  SecurityOfficer = 1L << 0,
  SecurityAssistant = 1L << 1,
  //...some referee of every type you can immagine
  LastAssistantAtTheMoment = 1L << 63,
  //...
}
```

Now our fat `bitwise` `enum` is completely saturated, and our client have recentely asked to add new type official roles to manage new activities.

I know, this is not the best approach to manage this scenario, this choice are in place from 8 years without problems, and no one could imagine how things would evolve, now we are waiting to rewrite completely our application, but at the same time we must continue to maintain old application with little changes.

I think we can maintein old solution based upon this BW simply change our `long` in `ulong` in our code and using `numeric(20,0)` on SQL-side, this could give us very large margin.

There is something I have missed in my conclusions, which can cause the not applicability of solution?

thanks in advance for your suggestions

Comment: `ulong` and `long` has thesame number of bits, so I don't see how switching to `ulong` would let you squeeze additional info into your flag combination.

Comment: At most you get 1 bit, though you can do that simply by using a negative value anyway.

Comment: Thanks all for your answer and comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how going from `long` to `ulong` would help. Both types have the same number of bits, and you've already used up all of them AFAIK. At best, you'd gain the sign bit, but that's no long-term solution.

One likely solution is to introduce two new database tables:

- `RefereeTypes` (having one entry for each of your `enum` values);
- `FooReferees` (an n:n association table that links each business entity to 1 or more `RefereeTypes`.

In your code, instead of `enum` properties on your business entities, you'd have collections of `RefereeType`... which probably would mean quite a rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you missed anything. In fact, at the moment you aren't using the full size of the `long`, since you didn't use the range below 0.

Instead of using `ulong`, you could opt to keep using `long`, but start using negative values.

But as stated in comments, this would only gain 1 bit, so not really something that would help the long term.